# django-machina search feature not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-machina

I am using django-machina for creating forums. But the search feature provided by machina is not working. I have followed [the docs](https://django-machina.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html). And have also updated the index as mentioned. But still the search is not working. I can't see any error in the log and there are no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the solution [here](https://github.com/ellmetha/django-machina/issues/245#issuecomment-943328320). After adding settings please do python3 manage.py update_index or you can do it by code

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command('update_index')
```